# jquery datepicker function not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I wrote a jquery function to add a new row with a datepicker in one of the td's. It works perfectly in chrome and safari but it doesn't work in firefox and i have no idea as to why.

Heres a jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/yFEkW/1/

Anybody know a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Basically passing a parameter on a callback call is not safe to use. 
try something like this:

```
var a = $('<a href="#" class="remove">x</a>');
a.click(function() {
    remove_it(idtag);
    return false; // use this to not try and navigate to the href
});
$('#rate_exception_table').find('tbody')
.append($("<tr id='" + idtag + "'>")
    .append($('<td>').append(""))
    .append($('<td>').append(""))
    .append($('<td>').append(picker))
    .append($('<td>').append(a))
);
```

Comment: didn't change anything...The row still isn't being added to the table

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. Changed "event.timestamp" to "new Date().getTime()"

working fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/yFEkW/3/